# Drupal 7 PHP: How to customize the webform module confirmation page?

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I include the webform in site, now when I submit the form, then I need to give the confirmation to user that your request has been submitted & I need to show the user that, how many request he submitted in the system like "Previous submission" page.

For this, I want to customize the webform-confirmation.tpl.php in webform module, I tried to include webform.report.inc and using webform_results_table($node, 0), displaying table but it will not give the Operation view, edit, delete.

Please help me to find out the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

please copy this code in _alter hook of your custom module 
costom_module_menu_alter(&$items){

```
$items['node/%webform_menu/done']= array(
    'page callback' => 'confirmation',// custom method on submission of form
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
   );
}
```

and define your own code in confirmation function

clear whole cache